# Matching any digit, word character, or a space 46 or more times before a less than sign

Tags: regex, notepad++

### Objective

I want to match any digit, word character, or space **46 or more times** before a `<` sign.

**One note** is that I'm trying to use this RegEx in Notepad++ before plugging it into the C# code.

### Data

```
<Elem1>123 ABC Street</Elem1> // should NOT match
<Elem1>123637 ABC Street Suite 1, Kalamzoo, FL 15264-8574</Elem1>
```

### RegEx

I currently have the following RegEx:

```
^.*<Elem1>[\d\w\s]{46,}?
```

and I can't figure out why this `[\d\w\s]{46,}?` won't match the inner portion of the element.

I look forward to your answers!

Comment: Why don't you just capture the string between the tags and check the length once captured?

Comment: @fge, primarily because I'm trying to find an exception across the file. So, assume for a moment that I have thousands of these elements and I need to find any of them that are greater than 45 characters in length to produce some exception information. My apologies for not being clearer on my intentions as a whole.

Comment: I recommend [`Espresso`](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) - it's great for editing and testing regex's

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't match because the input contains commas and hyphens, which are not part of any of the three character classes you include.

This would match:

```
^.*<Elem1>[\d\w\s,-]{46,}?
```

Additionally, it only makes sense to include the start of input anchor and then go on to say "oh, ignore any characters you find before an `<Elem1>`" if the regex runs in multiline mode. Otherwise, the same effect can be achieved with just

```
<Elem1>[\d\w\s,-]{46,}?
```

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `<Elem1>[\w\s]{46,}`

Comment: Won’t match the given example, as commas and dashes are not included.

Comment: @poke "I want to match any digit, word character, or space 46 or more times before a < sign." any commas and dashes

Comment: Just saying that it won’t match the given example data, and I think mentioning this fault in OP’s “matching description” is necessary, especially as it is the main reason why his expression fails.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash groups only contain digits, word characters and whitespace, so commas and dashes (as in your example) are not included. Also, if you really want to match *everything* between the tags, you should drop the `?` to make it greedy, and maybe add the closing tag to it too. You can then just use a capturing group to get the inner content: ([Example](http://regexr.com?33d62))

```
^.*<Elem1>([\d\w\s,-]{46,})</
```

Alternatively, if you want to make sure you catch other characters as well, you could just accept any character other than the `<` symbol inside the tag:

```
^.*<Elem1>([^<]{46,})</
```

Comment: +1 for coming up with a pattern that matches everything but the '<' symbol. I was going to suggest this myself but saw you had beaten me to it :-)